# UITextview show vertical scrollbar all the time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I am trying to show vertical scrollbar on uitextview at the beginning with the code
but it isn't doing so.

```
UITextView *txtView=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80,self.view.frame.size.width-20,self.view.frame.size.height/2)];    
[txtView setEditable:NO];
[txtView setSelectable:NO];
[txtView setText:self.secret];
[txtView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[txtView setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor ]];
[txtView setFont:font];
txtView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
[txtView flashScrollIndicators];
[self.view addSubview:txtView];
```

Comment: `flashScrollIndicators` in the `viewDidAppear:` when user actually sees the screen.

Answer (score 10):

If you just write `[textView flashScrollIndicators];` it will flash only once when your textView is created or page is loaded. There is not any code or method which display `flashScrollIndicators` continuously/permanently.

For do it you need to take help of `NSTimer` with very low time interval, and write code of flash indicator of textView in method of the timer. such like

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001f target:self selector:@selector(flashIndicator) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; // set time interval as per your requirement.
```

call method

```
-(void)flashIndicator
{
  //here you need to write code:
  [txtView flashScrollIndicators];
}
```

For more clarify:

> UITextView comes under UIScrollView class. So there is a method  flashScrollIndicators that you can call to prompts the user that the view is scrollable. It only flashes once for few seconds where user comes to a page that contains UIScrollView or its subclass. You may set timer to call this method more than one time.

Answer (score -1):

You can use setContentSize property for this. By setting it larger than the textview you can se scrolling indicators.

Comment: [txtView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height+100)]; Doesnt work